# How to define a name that has boolean value true or false

Tags: java

My program has many functions with a boolean input true or false. And the logic is when it's left, it's true; when it's right, it's false.

So instead of typing

```
myFuncton(true) //input is left
myFunction(false) //input is right
```

I want to be able to call myFunction like this:

```
myFunction(LEFT)
myFunction(RIGHT)
```

So it's much easier to understand my program

In short, how do I define a name with boolean value in JAVA?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me that a boolean is the best fit for your situation, since your goal is not to check for true or false, but rather to see what direction is desired. And if you did use a boolean, which direction should be considered "true"? which false? And what if you instead wanted to add UP and DOWN? Again, a boolean doesn't seem like a great fit.

It looks like your best bet is to instead use an enum:

```
enum Direction {
  LEFT, RIGHT
}
```

And then define your method:

```
public void myFunction(Direction dir) {
  if (dir == Direction.LEFT) {
    // go left
  } else {
    // go right
  }
}
```

This gives you the advantage of **compile time type checking** and self-documentation (as per @sqrfv in comments) and so is much better than using a String or a boolean. Also note that enums can have parameters and methods, and thus are much more powerful than String or boolean types.

---

For example, I wanted to use an enum to associate key strokes with directions for a Swing Key Bindings project, and created an enum actually called Direction like so:

```
enum Direction {
   UP("Up", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0)),
   DOWN("Down", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0)),
   LEFT("Left", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0)),
   RIGHT("Right", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0));

   Direction(String text, KeyStroke keyStroke) {
      this.text = text;
      this.keyStroke = keyStroke;
   }
   private String text;
   private KeyStroke keyStroke;

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public KeyStroke getKeyStroke() {
      return keyStroke;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return text;
   }
}
```

And then used it in my key bindings like so:

```
class Board2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 200;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   public static final String DIRECTION = "direction";
   private Direction direction = null;

   public Board2() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Board2"));
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

      for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
         inputMap.put(dir.getKeyStroke(), dir.getText());
         actionMap.put(dir.getText(), new MyArrowBinding(dir));
      }
   }

   private class MyArrowBinding extends AbstractAction {
      private Direction dir;

      public MyArrowBinding(Direction dir) {
         super(dir.getText());
         this.dir = dir;
         putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, dir);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         setDirection(dir);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public void setDirection(Direction direction) {
      Direction oldValue = this.direction;
      Direction newValue = direction;
      this.direction = newValue;

      firePropertyChange(DIRECTION, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public Direction getDirection() {
      return direction;
   }
}
```

Comment: Enums are self-documenting

Comment: enums aren't always self-documenting.  Don't let anyone ever use "self-documenting" as an excuse for not putting necessary comments in their code.  In this case it's clear enough, though.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that enums can be used in a `switch`

Comment: @Quincunx: good point, but now days, Strings can be used as well. Also an [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is a very compact and efficient mapping.

Answer (score 10):

Use final variables, final makes sure you cant change the variable's values.

```
final boolean LEFT = true; 
final boolean RIGHT = false;
```

then you can use them like this

```
myFunction(LEFT)
myFunction(RIGHT)
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, Thanks !

Comment: Actually `Boolean` could have an uppercase 'B' as that's a type too (and `final Boolean LEFT = true;` would work due to autoboxing). `final` does have to be lower cased.

Answer (score 2):

Look in to defining constants. You'll want them public/protected/private depending on your use.

`static final boolean LEFT = true;`

`static final boolean RIGHT = false;`

Edit: made RIGHT false.

Answer (score 0):

```
Final int LEFT = 0
Final int RIGHT = 1
```

That's how I did my keystrokes, except there was forward and backwards included.

Comment: `Final` should be lowercase: `final`